# Fierz Identity calculation

Tags: spinors, dirac-matrices, trace

While reading an article, it's said that to simplify the following Dirac structure $$\left(P_Lv_j^d\bar{v}^s_kP_R\right)_{\alpha\beta}\tag{1}\label{1}$$ where $j,k$ are color indices and $d,s$ indicate which quarks the spinor refer to, we're using Fierz identities projecting onto the set of complete operators (we are in dimension $4$) for objects containing two Lorentz indices  $$P_L, P_R, \gamma^\mu P_L, \gamma^\mu P_R, \sigma^{\mu\nu}$$The $P_{L/R}$ operators are the Weyl projection operators. The only relevant structure for $(\ref{1})$ is the $\gamma^\mu P_R$ structure, so we project on it using $\frac{1}{2}\text{Tr}\,\gamma^\mu P_L\cdots$. Now the article says that $$\frac{1}{2}\text{Tr}\,\gamma^\mu P_L P_Lv^d_j\bar{v}^s_k P_R = -\frac{1}{2}\bar{v}^s_k\gamma^\mu P_L v^d_j$$ I think that what is going on is just that $P_L^2=P_L$ so that $$\frac{1}{2}\text{Tr}\,\gamma^\mu P_L P_Lv^d_j\bar{v}^s_k P_R = \frac{1}{2}\text{Tr}\,\gamma^\mu  P_Lv^d_j\bar{v}^s_k P_R = \frac{1}{2}\text{Tr}\,P_R\gamma^\mu P_L P_Lv^d_j\bar{v}^s_k = \frac{1}{2}\text{Tr}\,\gamma^\mu P_L P_Lv^d_j\bar{v}^s_k =\\= \frac{1}{2}\text{Tr}\,\gamma^\mu P_Lv^d_j\bar{v}^s_k$$ where I used the cyclicity of the trace, the fact that $P_L\gamma^\mu = \gamma^\mu P_R$ since $\gamma_5$ anticommutes with all the $\gamma^\mu$, and again the projector property. But then I don't know how to go to the last result. I imagine that the minus sign comes from the anticommutation of the $v$ spinors but then I don't know how he got rid of the trace.

Comment: You are right that the minus sign comes from anticommutation of  spinors. And  $\text{Tr}\,\gamma^\mu P_Lv^d_j\bar{v}^s_k = -Tr(\bar{v}^s_k\gamma^\mu P_L v^d_j) = -\bar{v}^s_k\gamma^\mu P_L v^d_j$, since the spinor inner product has already done the tracing in spinor indices for ya.

Comment: @MadMax Ohw ok, that's what I thought was going on but I was not so sure. Thank you very much!

Comment: Another home work for you is Fierz identity for $\left(P_Lv_j^d\bar{v}^s_kP_L\right)_{\alpha\beta}$, where the $\sigma^{\mu\nu}$ term comes into the picture.

Comment: @MadMax Cool, I'll have a go at it! Thank you